# How to optimize the quiz buttons in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, logic

I am working on a building a quiz app.
I have already built it. but so far I am not happy with my code. I believe the code is not scalable and concise enough. I was wondering if you could help me make my code better.

what I need is, when the user clicks one of the options, if it is correct, then make the button clicked into green background. otherwise, red and correct buttons into green.
for now, it is working as it should. but lets say down the road, I have to have questions that contains more than 2 options like 3, 5, or even more. then, this code will not work. and the logic gets even uglier.

Could you please help me out of it?

```
const questions = [
  {
    id: 1,
    question: "which one of them is fruit?",
    options: ["apple", "rice"],
    answers: ["correct", "wrong"]
  },
]

function App() {

  const [btnA, setBtnA] = React.useState("gray")
  const [btnB, setBtnB] = React.useState("gray")

  const handleButtonA = (e, answer) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if(answer == "correct") {
      setBtnA("green");
    }
    if(answer === "wrong") {
      setBtnA("red")
      setBtnB("green")
    }
  }

  const handleButtonB = (e, answer) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(answer === "correct") {
      setBtnB("green")
    }
    if(answer === "wrong") {
      setBtnA("green")
      setBtnB("red")
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {questions.map(q => {
        return (
          <div key={q.id}>
            <h3>{q.question}</h3>
            <button style={{background: btnA}} onClick={e => handleButtonA(e, q.answers[0])}>{q.options[0]}</button>
            <button style={{background: btnB}} onClick={e => handleButtonB(e, q.answers[1])}>{q.options[1]}</button>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: For review of already-working code, please post on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code won't work with multiple questions. Since you share the same state for all buttons, clicking the right/wrong button will update all of them.

2nd of all, I'd recommend you change from this:

```js
options: ["apple", "rice"],
answers: ["correct", "wrong"]
```

to:

```js
options: [
    "apple",
    "rice",
],
correct: 0
```

Where correct is the index is of the correct option. This way you don't have to check for a string, and in general, it is more oriented.

Now, we dont need to know the colors in the state, we just need to know if the question has been attempted or not. For that, we can create a state which is an array.

```js
const [quizData, setQuizData] = useState(questions.map(question => { 
    return {
        attempted: -1
    }
}))
```

Now finally, we can loop over each element in the array.

```js
return (
<div className="App">
  {questions.map((q, questionIndex) => {
    const currData = quizData[questionIndex];
    
    // Method to handle when button is clicked
    // valid is weather the question clicked was valid
    const handleClick = (index) => {
    
        // we use a method which recieves the currentState when using setState
        // in order to prevent react scheduling issues
        setQuizData((prevData) => {
            // for the current question, set attempted to true
            prevData[questionIndex].attempted = index;
            
            // destructure the array because react doesnt work well with returning the same object instance
            return [
                ...prevData
            ]
        })
    }

    return (
      <div key={q.id}>
        <h3>{q.question}</h3>
        {/* Looop over each option */}
        {question.options.map((option, index) => {
        
            // take gray as the default color
            let color = "gray";
            
            // if the user has attempted already, check to change the color
            if (currData.attempted >= 0) {
                if (index == currData.attempted) {
                    if (index == q.correct) {
                        color = "green";
                    }
                    else {
                        color = "red"
                    }
                }
                else if (index == q.correct) {
                    color = "greeen"
                }
            }
            
            // over here the button's enabled property is something I added, but you can remove that if you'd like
            return (
                <button
                enabled={!currData.attempted}
                key={index}
                style={{background: color}}
                onClick={() => handleClick(index)}>
                    {option}
                </button>
            )
        }}
      </div>
    )
  })}
</div>
);
```

So in the end, our code is:

```js
const questions = [
  {
    id: 1,
    question: "which one of them is fruit?",
    options: [
        "apple",
        "rice",
    ],
    correct: 0
  },
]

function App() {

    const [quizData, setQuizData] = useState(questions.map(question => { 
        return {
            attempted: -1
        }
    }))
    

    return (
    <div className="App">
      {questions.map((q, questionIndex) => {
        const currData = quizData[questionIndex];

        // Method to handle when button is clicked
        // valid is weather the question clicked was valid
        const handleClick = (index) => {

            // we use a method which recieves the currentState when using setState
            // in order to prevent react scheduling issues
            setQuizData((prevData) => {
                // for the current question, set attempted to true
                prevData[questionIndex].attempted = index;

                // destructure the array because react doesnt work well with returning the same object instance
                return [
                    ...prevData
                ]
            })
        }

        return (
          <div key={q.id}>
            <h3>{q.question}</h3>
            {/* Looop over each option */}
            {question.options.map((option, index) => {

                // take gray as the default color
                let color = "gray";

                // if the user has attempted already, check to change the color
                if (currData.attempted >= 0) {
                    if (index == currData.attempted) {
                        if (index == q.correct) {
                            color = "green";
                        }
                        else {
                            color = "red"
                        }
                    }
                    else if (index == q.correct) {
                        color = "greeen"
                    }
                }

                // over here the button's enabled property is something I added, but you can remove that if you'd like
                return (
                    <button
                    enabled={!currData.attempted}
                    key={index}
                    style={{background: color}}
                    onClick={() => handleClick(index)}>
                        {option}
                    </button>
                )
            }}
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
    );
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help, However, I do not need to change the background color of incorrect option when the user clicks the correct option. 

for example if the user clicks the apple, it needs to change the apple button to green and rice stays grey. if the user clicks on rice, then rice to red and apple to green. how can i implement that? I think we have to change the logic of your code.

Comment: Hey, thanks for clarifying! To be clear: clicking the correct button makes it green and all others stay red, but if you click the wromg one, all wrong ones turn red and the correct one turns green? Or is it that clicking an incorrect one turns that particular button red, and the correct button green

Comment: sorry for the confusion. so clicking the correct answer makes it green and others will stay gray. in this way, user knows that he got the correct answer. if user clicks the wrong answer, the button clicked will turn red and the actual correct one should turn green. in this way, user knows that user made a mistake and which one was the correct answer.

Comment: I really like your code and it looks clean and concise. I was wondering if you could help me out with the situation above. I tried to modified by making another state, but I got lost.

Comment: Ah, alright. I have edited the code, and it should work now

Comment: thank you so much. appreciate that. it is great